# User unable to trigger Custom Action - SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-actions

I have a custom action that is in the ribbon. when it is clicked SPD has it programmed to open the intitiation form. You fill in some boxes and then click start to initiate the workflow.

I am OWNER.  The other user is OWNER.

We are testing it out and she gets the following image:

[image]

But I am having no problems.

What is doing this.

Tammy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on "Technical Details" it will show you the correlation ID of the error.  You will then need to look up that ID in the ULS logs to find out what the error is.